# how to configure conjure aniseed parinfer in lua for neovim clojure development?

Tags: neovim, lua, filetype-clojure

I'm using neovim for clojure development. I would like to setup below plugins.

1. Olical/aniseed
2. Olical/conjure
3. gpanders/nvim-parinfer
4. PaterJason/cmp-conjure

I don't know how to setup rudimentary config in lua. All I see is setup in fennel. I don't know either fennel or vimscript.

All I have done so far is installed the plugins in neovim using below lua script -

```
use 'Olical/aniseed'

use 'Olical/conjure'

use 'gpanders/nvim-parinfer'

use 'PaterJason/cmp-conjure'
```

I don't know how to setup config in lua. Does have one have setup for the above four plugins in lua?

Comment: Judging by your [newer question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/39881/51), I think you've figured out your question?

Comment: I think I added it but not sure whether those config are correct