# "Error detected while processing TextChangedI Autocommands for "<buffer=4>":" ParInfer Neovim

Tags: neovim, plugin, filetype-clojure

I'm setting up parinfer plugin for lisp development in neovim.

I've installed neovim plugin using below code -

```
use 'gpanders/nvim-parinfer'
```

And I've also setup below configuration

```
-- parinfer options
vim.cmd([[
let g:parinfer_mode = 1
let g:parinfer_force_balance = 1
let g:parinfer_filetypes = ["clojure", "schema", "lisp", "racket", "fennel"]
]])
```

Now when I edit any clojure files I get below error trace -

> Error detected while processing TextChangedI Autocommands for "<buffer=4>":
>
> E5108: Error executing lua ...e/pack/packer/start/nvim-parinfer/lua/parinfer/setup.lua:158: attempt to call a nil value
>
> stack traceback:
>
> ```
>    ...e/pack/packer/start/nvim-parinfer/lua/parinfer/setup.lua:158: in function 'invoke_parinfer'
>
>   ...e/pack/packer/start/nvim-parinfer/lua/parinfer/setup.lua:208: in function <...e/pack/packer/start/nvim-parinfer/lua/parinfer/setup.lua:199>
> ```

What is wrong with my config and how can I fix this?

[image: parinfer error]

Comment: Also reported (and resolved) on the plugin's issue tracker: https://github.com/gpanders/nvim-parinfer/issues/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`:help g:parinfer_mode`](https://github.com/gpanders/nvim-parinfer/blob/82bce5798993f4fe5ced20e74003b492490b4fe8/doc/parinfer.txt#L45); the valid values include `'smart'` and other strings but not `1`.

Hat tip to [the maintainers](https://github.com/gpanders/nvim-parinfer/issues/15).